# Get index of next Row under Chart

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know if there is a better way to get the index of the next row under a chart that is placed in a worksheet. I am placing multiple charts with the `.parent.Left /.Top` properties, not in a range.

I have multiple choices how do implement that, but I find none of these attrative :

- Go trough every row in the worksheet, check if the `.Top` position of the row is below the chart `.Top + .Heigth`
- get the default height of a cell, divise the `.Height` of the Chart with it, and i get the approximate number of rows that the chart is filling.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [BottomRightCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196408(v=office.14).aspx) property of the `Shape`. For instance:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ChartName").BottomRightCell.Row
```

... And then simply add 1 to that result.

EDIT: The `Chart`'s parent is a `ChartObject`, which has the same property.

Comment: firstly thanks for the quick answer ! exactly what i was looking for. The chart object also has the same property.

Comment: actually the `chart` object does not have the property, but the `chartObject` object has it. The parent of the `chart` object is the `chartObject`.

Comment: The parent of `Chart` - at least for my current example - is a `ChartObject`. So I stand corrected, it was not a Shape ;-) Is that enough to cancel the accepted answer though?

Comment: Just wanted to be sure, sorry about that. You're edit says it's a ChartArea, which is it now ? =)

Comment: Hahaha, I really was tired yesterday. It's indeed a `ChartObject`, and I'll correct my answer to reflect that.